# Parser exception for /google-play-services_lib/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to import the google-play-services_lib in Eclipse like they say in this tutorial (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) but it gives the error below and I can't seem to find a decent solution. I've imported a copy not the original one, it's on the same disk...

Parser exception for /google-play-services_lib/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.

Comment: Hi @Milo, seems like the below answer I posted should address your question. Perhaps you could confirm by ticking it? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you copy your google-play-services_lib over, don't copy to inside your Eclipse's **"workspace"** folder. Because when you import the library, the Eclipse will override the content within the google-play-services_lib folder and corrupt it.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Stupid me... Thank you!

Comment: Had this problem for more than 5 hours, this was the solution. You are the man!!

Comment: yes, I made the same mistake - copied the folder straight to `workspace` and then hit "Copy project files into workspace"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try opening the google_play_service manifest ?
From the exception message it looks like it has been somehow corrupted

Comment: Yes it becomes empty after the import. After each import.

Comment: importing a project doesn't do any modification to your resources. You just have to import the project and then add a dependency to this project into your own project

Comment: I know but now it does. If I put the project in my workspace it's fine, once imported blank. The error prevents me from adding the dependency. I don't get it, did exactly what the guide said. Found other people with the same problem but no clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will occur if you copy the library project in your project workspace. While doing the import ... import it as an existing android code from the adt installation...

for me it's something like...
D:\Android Dev\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

and then tick the option of copying it current workspace during the import.
This solved the problem for me and it will not clear manifest or resources file.

Secondly... don't forget that this line in manifest should have the same android:minSdkVersion as your main android project