# R.Java not generated in old project and newly created project also

Tags: android

Here I am getting weird problem with eclipse. Whenever I tried to import my project, which is worked well. suddenly I am getting this error. 
Even I tried to create new project, it hasn’t R.Java also.
  I also tried with making new workspace to solve this problem, but still it is not solve. 
  So, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Not a answer but Eclipse is not supported anymore. Better invest time in migrating to android studio+gradle

Comment: If your IDE couldn't generate R.java on the rebuild, there must be some problem in your resource package. You've the find and fix the faulty xml file or whatever in res. Then ide generates R.java successfully again.

Comment: Could it be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756666/parser-exception-for-google-play-services-lib-androidmanifest-xml-premature-en/22252539#22252539?

Comment: @asozcan , Actually My project is working well. And if I am trying with new (HelloWorld) project, it also hasn't any R.java file.. Please help me to solve this

Comment: @X3Btel, If I am trying to import my current project in android Studio, it also give me the error. and i can't import it. I tried also this trick.

Comment: Oops, it looks like your JDK or AndroidStudio version is outdated. Error with HelloWorld not make sense.

Comment: @asozcan Yeah!! I solved it. Update my platform-tools to older version and getting solved it finally!!!!!!